# DynamoDB find nearest integer key

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamodb table with hash as unix time, and primarykey as name

Is there a way to get the closest unix time, if it cannot find the exact one?

So if I am searching for (123343445, john), it will either return (123343445, john) or the next closest which may be (123343446, john)

I would ideally not want to check for an item then iterate up or down until I find a matching time because I do not know what the time interval is and in most cases it will not be equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example in nodejs, for other languages it is similar. The code may not be perfect, but the pseudo-code is! :)

```
const params = {
    TableName: MyTableName,
    KeyConditionExpression: '#pk = :pk AND #sk >= :sk',
    Limit: 1,
    ScanIndexForward: true,
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      '#pk': 'name',
      '#sk': 'timestamp',
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':pk': 'john', # may use some variable
      ':sk': '123343445', # may use some variable
    },
};

# /!\ Not sure about the exact syntax
new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()
  .query(params).promise()
  .then((item) => { console.log(item); });
```

Please note:

- `KeyConditionExpression` will return **all** the items after the given timestamp (`123343445`),
- `ScanIndexForward: true` will start from your timestamp
- `Limit: 1` which will return the first match only.

You may use other languages or the aws-cli, look for these parameters, they should be available.

Should you want, you may do similar queries on indexes, all you have to do is to add the `IndexName: 'STRING_VALUE',` in `params`.